# include script to page

Tags: javascript, https, include, execute

I am trying to include script to any client's page. I create firefox extension which find  tag and appendChild there with my script. And that works fine.
And it works when client use http pages (It load properly and execute)
But that doesn't work when client use https pages (it load properly but not execute).

I have the same code for http and https. In my code I haven't special http and https conditions. Anyone know what can be wrong ?

I think code is ok, but ok, examples:

Injecting script (in extension):

```
   var myScript = top.window.content.document.createElement('script');
   myScript.type = 'text/javascript';
   myScript.setAttribute('src','http://path/to/my/script.js');
   myScript.setAttribute('onload', 'firefoxInit()');
   top.window.content.document.getElementsByTagName('body')[0].appendChild(myScript);
```

Code to execute:

```
var manipulate = (function(){
   alert('duper execute');
}());
```

Comment: JavaScript execution should not be influenced by the choice of HTTP or HTTPS as protocol. There must be something else going on. Impossible to analyze without code samples.

Comment: ok, I added code examples. Like I said http page works ok - alert my message, and https doesn't. Any idea ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

https will not let you run insecure content like scripts from a non-secured url, so your http-hosted script.js won't be allowed to run. Mixed content is blocked by default in the current versions of Firefox and Chrome (not checked IE)

Comment: It looks you are right, but for example Tamper and Grease Monkeys works also for https page. Have you any indea wow do they works ?

Comment: no, but I'd guess they don't load scripts as `<script>` elements on a page but instead download the data using an xhr and then pass that data to a bit that loads it in